# How could I fix the display layout for ASP.net MVC project?

Tags: c#, html, css

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 and I copied this code from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). The layout of my page is showing:
[Output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH59C.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Movie App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">Movie App</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - Movie App - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This code is from the _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: did you make sure that you have the /lib/bootstrap directory in the project? if not you need to add bootstrap to the project

Comment: ASP.NET is a server-side platform. **It has absolutely nothing to do with client-side layout**. You're getting confused because ASP.NET's default project templates include Bootstrap.

Comment: Look at the Network tab of your Developer Tools' window to see why the request for the stylesheet is failing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your layout page can't load CSS and JS files referenced in the layout page. Please make sure your project contains these files according to the below file structure.

```
wwwroot
  |-> css
    |-> site.css
  |-> lib
    |-> bootstrap
      |-> dist
        |-> css
          |-> bootstrap.min.css
        |-> js
          |-> bootstrap.bundle.min.js
  |-> jquery
    |-> dist
      |-> jquery.min.js
  |-> js
    |-> site.js
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Please let me know if otherwise.